# The package at "node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/src/index.js" attempted to import the Node standard library module "crypto"

Tags: react-native, expo, web3js

I'm building a Ethereum ERC20 tokens support wallet in React Native, I have been struggling on this particular issue for the past few days and I hope someone could help.

> The package at "node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/src/index.js" attempted
>   to import the Node standard library module "crypto"

Here is my package.json file.

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^33.0.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.4",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.2.0",
    "web3": "1.0.0-beta.34",
    "cryptico": "^1.0.2",
    "native-base": "2.8.0",
    "node-libs-browser": "2.1.0",
    "react-native-crypto": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-randombytes": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.1.1",
    "babel-cli": "6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1"
  },
```

Please advise!
I have followed this link as well, no luck ! 
https://gist.github.com/dougbacelar/29e60920d8fa1982535247563eb63766

Answer (score 0):

i have 2 answers for you :)

1) use ethers.js since its rich and have default support for React Native

2) copy shims from link that you provided to your project and import it on App.js file at top so your web3 lib should work

Comment: Hi how good is it for `ethers.js` running on RN 0.63 app? It seems require hacking to make `web3.js` working with React Native app.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.babelrc` file to define optional configuration, First, install the dependencies:

You can try install `npm install --save crypto-browserify`

Then add plugins config to your `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-expo"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx-source"]
    }
  },
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["./app"],
      "alias": {
        "crypto": "crypto-browserify"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

and Please import the wallet module.

```js
import crypto from 'crypto'
```

You can run `npm i --save-dev rn-nodeify@latest` and `rn-nodeify --install "stream"`

if not `./node_modules/.bin/rn-nodeify --install "stream"`

`rn-nodeify` will create a `shim.js` in the project root directory

example

```js
// index.ios.js or index.android.js or App.js
// make sure you use `import` and not `require`!
import './shim.js'
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16kwx.png)

[image: Structure_1]
[image: Structure_2]
[image: App.js]

Comment: It prompts me this error when I installed the crypto-browserify.

Comment: I don't see any error codes on the screen, just the error message and I have snapped it and attached here. Please advise

Comment: I think "vm" is required here. I got an error which telling the "vm" is missing.

Comment: I think this might easier for you to advise me. I have attached the screenshots of my current folder structure, do you see any things missing here? I'm still getting the error complaint about the "stream" missing.

Comment: `./node_modules/.bin/rn-nodeify --install "vm"`